# Localization for exceptions in Android

Tags: android, exception, localization

I am developing application for multi-languages. The static strings in my application like "**Are you want to quit?**" have been replaced with the key values in **strings.xml** file from android application's res folder. But I am unable to give the localized messages for exceptions in my application. I have tried the **getLocalizedMessage()** in the catch block, but this also **return message in English** only. **How can I give the localized messages for Exceptions in Android.?**

Answer (score 1):

The exception responses are in the language of the current thread locale.

[These are the locales possible](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The exceptions are in the english locale only, both in error.getMessage() and error.getLocalizedMessage(). I am tried to set the android:configChanges="locale" and change the device language to some other language, still the exception is throws in English language. Is there any other method to get the localized message from catch block.?

Comment: I wonder if your device doesn't have the other locales.  Can you change the locale, in general on the device?  Perhaps it is not localizable.

Comment: In my device some other locales are there. If I am using the res folder strings those strings are replaced according to device locale. But in the exceptions always throws in english language only for some other locale language for example french in the device. Is there any way to get the localized string for exceptions in Android.?